# How to redirect the value in `<s:property/>` of one jsp page to the `<input type="text"/>` of another jsp page..?

Tags: jsp, struts2, taglib

How to redirect the value in `<s:property/>` of one jsp page to the `<input type="text"/>` of another jsp page..?

i have two jsp pages : one.jsp and two.jsp

one.jsp :

```
 <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Jsp - one</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>One JSP</h1>
             <s:iterator value="u" begin="0" end="0">
    <s:property value="uid" />
</s:iterator>
             <a href="two.jsp">Go to two.jsp</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

two.jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Jsp - two</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Two JSP</h1>
         <input type="text" id="two" name="two" value="<%=request.getParameter("uid")%>" /> //in this textfield i want the value of <s:property/> of one.jsp. But i am getting "null" in it.
         <a href="one.jsp">Go to one.jsp</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note : one.jsp is using struts2 taglib and the value of `<s:property/>` is fetched from an action class which return some list `u`, list `u` is of type `users` which is having a unique `uid`. I have done the mapping of class and table in database properly. And two.jsp is not using any taglib. two.jsp has nothing to do with the database or taglib. It simply has one link from one.jsp.
In the `<input type="text">` of two.jsp, i want the value of `<s:property/>` of one.jsp. But i am getting `"null"` in it.
Please give some way to get it.

Comment: Your have a list of uid on page one and whant put all of them in your input on page two? I think not. It's look like your want select one of the values and pass it to page to. So use <s:select/> instead of <s:iterator/> and pass selected value as usual. Add a form to your page and use submit instead of link or use some javascript and add selected value to href or whatever

Comment: thanks for your comment and pointing out my need. Your r right i need only one and the very 1st value of the list. So i edited with begin="0" end ="0" in the <s:iterator/> tag. As u r saying to use <s:select/> then how can fetch the value from an action class from which list 'u' is returned..? Is there a way to do same with <s:select/> then please share.

Comment: on `one.jsp`, you can put your value and your `a` tag to a form, then you should access your value on page two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:iterator value="u" begin="0" end="0">
     <a href="two.jsp?uid=<s:property value="uid"/>">Go to two.jsp</a>
</s:iterator>
```

Or

```
<s:iterator value="u" begin="0" end="0">
   <s:set var="valToSend" value="uid" />
</s:iterator>

<a href="two.jsp?uid=<s:property value="valToSend"/>">Go to two.jsp</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

1 Your don't whant select uId from the list and your need pass first uid to page two:

```
  <body>
    <h1>One JSP</h1>
    <a href="two.jsp?uid=<s:property value="u.get(0)"/>">Go to two.jsp</a>
  </body>
```

2 Your want select uId from list

```
<body>
  <h1>One JSP</h1>
  <form action="two.jsp">
    <s:select name="uid" list="u" listKey="uid" listValue="uid"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go to two.jsp"/>
  </form>
</body>
```